# Gmail offline support with Gears

Tags: gmail, google-gears

How Gmail creates localcache for supporting offline? 
I found by check the http requests while syncing that it is done by simulating the http requests like webclient, is it correct? If yes, is this a documented method? can any other plugin use this?

Answer (score 1):

Google has [announced](http://gearsblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hello-html5.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+GearsApiBlog+%28Gears+API+Blog%29) that they reduce their efforts for Gears in favour for HTML5 and the new Webstorage API. So maybe you have a look at the [Webstorage Specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) and some [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/taking-a-dive-into-html5-web-storage).